# C # + NUnit + Selenium Grid - parallel launch of several browsers on one node

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, nunit-3.0

Use:
C# + WebDriver+NUnit + Grid,
Implementation using Page Object+Page Factory,
WebDriver 3.4.0,
Nunit 3.5.0,
Google Chrome Driver 2.36,
Mozilla Geckodrive 0.20.0,
last updated Chrome and FF browsers

I'm trying to learn how to implement parallel test runs. Now the task is next: running one TestFixture on node in two different browsers simultaneously. I'm doing like this:

```
[TestFixture("chrome")]
[TestFixture("firefox")]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
public class LoginTests : BaseObject
{
    public LoginTests(string browser)
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.SetCapability("browserName", browser);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.1.63:5555/wd/hub"), capability);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
    private static LoginPageHelper LoginPageHelper = new LoginPageHelper();

    [Test]
    public static void LoginOnMailru()
    {
        string email = "test.account.damir@mail.ru";
        string password = "q123123a";

        LoginPageHelper.
            DoLogin(email, password);
    }
}
```

After performing: run 2 browsers at the same time (chrome and FF). The test passed completely in the FF browser. Chrome executed only driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl) and an error appears

*Test name: SendingMailTestForLQ.Tests.LoginTests("chrome").LoginOnMailru
Result: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Could not find element by: By.Id: mailbox:submit*

What I'm doing wrong, why there is an error "Could not find element by: By.Id: mailbox:submit"? Thanks!
P.S. Sorry for my English.